# script execute again if the database have changes

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

can anyone help me how to do that my script only automatically execute again if the database has some changes only....in my current script it executes all the time according to the var `timer` `setInterval` in order to automatically update the output of the `textboxes` if i change the value in the database without the page refreshing or click the button again to execute the script.

i want to do is it will only execute again if there is some value changes in the table in the database...anyone know how to do it?

script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var timer ;
$('#send_search_form').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".search_form_input").val('');
        $(".empty_batchcode").html("Doesn't exist!");
        clearInterval(timer);
        updateTextboxes();

});
var $funiq_id         = $('#funiq_id'),
    $t_region         = $('#t_region'),
    $t_town           = $('#t_town'),
    $t_uniq_id        = $('#t_uniq_id'),
    $t_position       = $('#t_position'),
    $t_salary_grade   = $('#t_salary_grade'),
    $t_salary         = $('#t_salary');

function updateTextboxes(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"search.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: { term : $('#query').val() },
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result) {

        var ii = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
                    $funiq_id.html(result[i].value).show(); // reference
                    $t_region.val(result[i].region).show(); // reference
                    $t_town.val(result[i].town).show(); // reference
                    $t_uniq_id.val(result[i].uniq_id).show(); // reference
                    $t_position.val(result[i].position).show(); // reference
                    $t_salary_grade.val(result[i].salary_grade).show(); // reference
                    $t_salary.val(result[i].salary).show(); // reference
                    $('#id'+ii+'').val(result[i].atid).show();
                    $('#aic'+ii+'').val(result[i].atic).show();
                    $('#name'+ii+'').val(result[i].atname).show();
                    $('#other_qual'+ii+'').val(result[i].other_sum).show();
                    $('#interview'+ii+'').val(result[i].interview_sum).show();
            ii++;
            }


        if(timer == 1){

            timer = setTimeout(updateTextboxes,1000); 
        }

        }


    });

   timer = setInterval(updateTextboxes,50000);
}
});      
 </script>
```

search.php code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

    $q = $_GET['term'];
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("klayton");
    $query = mysql_query
("
SELECT DISTINCT 
ROUND((SELECT SUM(t2.inttotal)
 FROM app_interview2 AS t2 
 WHERE t2.atic = t.atic)/7,1)
 AS interview_sum,

ROUND((SELECT SUM(o2.ototal)
 FROM other_app2 AS o2 
 WHERE o2.oaic = t.atic)/7,1)
 AS other_sum,

atid,
atic,
atname,
region,
town,
uniq_id,
position,
salary_grade,
salary
FROM app_interview2 AS t
WHERE uniq_id = '$q'
GROUP BY t.atname HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.atic) ");

    $data = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $data[] = array(
            'value' => $row['uniq_id'],
            'atid' => $row['atid'],
            'atic' => $row['atic'],
            'region' => $row['region'],
            'town' => $row['town'],
            'uniq_id' => $row['uniq_id'],
            'position' => $row['position'],
            'salary_grade' => $row['salary_grade'],
            'salary' => $row['salary'],
            'atname' => $row['atname'],
            'other_sum' => $row['other_sum'],
            'interview_sum' => $row['interview_sum']
        );
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);

}

?>
```

Comment: two words not possible

Comment: You would need to a) store a representation of the current state in your javascript layer, b) periodically poll your PHP function with ajax (or use a websocket listener or similar) and c) compare the results of your poll with the current state representation.  Frameworks like [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) do some of this for you but you'd still need some mechanism to poll and update the data.

Comment: Or maybe simpler... you store a modified at-timestamp in the dba and compare this one in JS...

Answer (score 0):

Its hard, but you can do that. *(and that is the problem with ideas and computers: the answer is always yes, it just takes a while to make it..)*

### Ajax long polling

Say you are able to have ajax retrieve the results and show these to the user. Now in therory, if you execute the ajax request again, you should get the newer results. You could even do this in a loop! But thats not very efficient as for traffic and the user system. Instead, why not make the server delay its answer as long as possible, while it periodically checks (say once every two seconds) if the database gives a different result?

This is called long polling. Search results are complicated though, so lets look at this from a more simple perspective. Lets say the ajax call wants to cough up the newest/latest database entry, so it request a PHP file that executes this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

And the PHP file just returns the `id`. And lets append a debug `timestamp` to differentiate between individual requests. If all goes well, you'll only see the `timestamp` change when the `id` does.

Now the PHP does (psuedocode)

```
// Settings
$oldid = $_GET['oldid'];
$delay = 2; // in seconds
$timeout = 20; // in seconds, must be below server and browser timeout.

// Check until different, or timeout.
$timer = 0;
while (1) {
  // TODO: Execute query and populate $id

  // If different, return as JSON.
  if ($id!=$oldid) {
    die('{"ajax": {"poll": "OK","id": '.$id.',"timestamp": '.time().'}');
  }

  // If taking to long, stop.
  if ($timer>$timeout) { die('{"ajax": {"poll": "timeout"}}'); }
  $timer += $delay;

  // The artificial delay.
  sleep($delay);
}
```

Now if you'd call this using `somefile.php?oldid=3` and the latest DB entry is also 3, you get `timeout` back in 20 seconds. Unless within that time `id` changed to some other value.

Now the client side, where you execute the AJAX, should not start the next AJAX request until the first one is done. So dont use `setinterval()` but use `settimeout()`. If the reply is `timeout` you may not want to update the page contents.

And thats it!
The same goes for search results, but you should look into making a hash, CRC, timestamp, or other low-CPU method to see whether the result differs from what the new query results.

### Websockets

When web-sockets get standarized and implemented in all mayor browsers, that might be a better option. Its basically used just like long polling with a much higher timeout, so not much gain there.